# Rollback deployment on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I was doing an arm template deployment of Azure data factory from dev-ops pipelines. Mistakenly I have chosen `deployment mode` as `complete` because of that all the resources inside my target resource group are deleted(DW, ADF, Databricks and all other resources).

Is there any way to rollback?

Comment: The only thing is to take backup of all sources specially for production for the next time as it creates a big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unless everything was deployed by a single template - no. your only option is to redeploy individual templates. but that wont bring back any data you had.

if everything was deployed with a single template there is a `-previous` switch in powershell, but assuming all the extra things got deleted, this doesnt apply to your case.